# zlib1g and zlib1g-dev installed but showing 'zlib1g command not found' in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed the zlib1g and zlib1g-dev by this commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libssl-dev
```

but after I am trying to run the command but showing 'zlib1g: command not found'

```
zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

I checked whether the zlib1g is installed or not and its showing it is already installed the latest version

plz help anyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zlib1g` is not a linux command/executable binary.
`zlib1g` is a library and `zlib1g-dev` are headers for c/c++. You need to add linker flag `-lz` when compiling so it will include `zlib`.

Comment: r you saying the command would be like this? 'zlib1g zlib1g-dev -lz'?

Comment: I'm saying zlib1g isn't a command at all
It is a library use by c/c++

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed the zlib1g...
> `sudo apt install build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libssl-dev`

1. You didn't installed `zlib1g`. [`zlib1g`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/zlib1g) is called `zlib1g` not `libpcre` or `libssl`, installed with `sudo apt install zlib1g`, or with `zlib1g-dev` if you want to develop something with `zlib1g-dev`.
2. `zlib1g` [is a **library** not an **executable**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/zlib1g), which means it is used to put there, waiting for other executable or library to call it, not waiting for calling from a terminal command. You should detect an library by writing a program that `#include`s it or using a package manager command.